# JBoss 5.1.0 on JDK 1.6 - do I need to tweak the configuration to get it to work?

Tags: jboss, java

I am in the process of installing JBoss 5.1.0 on machines running JDK 1.6.0u21.

In the 5.1.0 [release notes](http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/jbossas/tags/JBoss_5_1_0_GA/build/docs/readme.html) there is the following paragraph in the section titled "Compatibility Issues from 5.0.0.GA":

> JBossAS 5.0.0.GA can be compiled with both Java5 & Java6. The Java5 compiled binary is our primary/recommended binary distribution. It has undergone rigorous testing and can run under both a Java 5 and a Java 6 runtime. When running under Java 6 you need to manually copy the following libraries from the JBOSS_HOME/client directory to the JBOSS_HOME/lib/endorsed directory, so that the JAX-WS 2.0 apis supported by JBossWS are used:

I am a little confused as to whether this paragraph is referring to JBoss 5.1.0 or JBoss 5.0.0. The release notes are definitely for JBoss 5.1.0, but this section refers to JBoss 5.0.0 and 5.1.0 definitely starts under JDK 1.6, though I have not yet deployed anything.

Do I need to copy the files specified, or is this warning actually for JBoss 5.0.0 and should therefore be ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The libraries (not listed above) are

```
jbossws-native-saaj.jar
jbossws-native-jaxrpc.jar
jbossws-native-jaxws.jar
jbossws-native-jaxws-ext.jar
```

You can check the `$JBOSS_HOME/lib/endorsed` directory yourself to see if they are already there. (I can confirm they are already in place for 5.1.0 Enterprise Edition, not sure about the community edition).

In any case you will only need these libraries if your application is using JBoss web services.